# destructor called before temporary should be out of scope

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, decltype, visual-studio-2015

I have a bit of code which fails under VS2015, but works under GCC. I'm pretty sure the bug is with Visual Studio but want to be sure that my understanding of decltype(auto) is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string zero_params()
{
  return "zero_params called.";
}

template< typename F >
auto test1( F f ) -> decltype(auto)
{
  return f();
}

int main() {
  cout << std::is_rvalue_reference< decltype(test1(zero_params)) >::value << endl;
  cout << test1(zero_params) << endl;

  cout << "Done!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Under Visual Studio the string returned by zero_params is deduced to be an rvalue reference. Furthermore the destructor of that object is called inside test1() where the return from the call to f happens (which seems a reasonable place to destruct a && object).

Under GCC the string returned is not deduced to be an rvalue reference. The destructor is called after use in the cout statement as I'd expect.

Specifying the return type to be 'string' instead of decltype(auto) under Visual Studio fixes it, as does using remove_reference_t on the return of f() inside test1.

My expectation would be that GCC is correct as the function signature for zero_params() is string, not string&& so I would expect the non-reference to 'bubble up' to the return type of test1 if it uses decltype(auto).

Is this a correct assessment?

---

LATE EDIT:

Another way I've found to get around this with VS2015 is to wrap the function given to test1 in a lambda:

```
cout << test1(zero_params) << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << test1( [](auto&&... ps) { return zero_params(std::forward<decltype(ps)>(ps)...); } ) << endl;
```

Comment: Right, `f()` is a prvalue, so `decltype` should deduce `std::string` rather than `std::string &&`.

Comment: Please file a bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post the link here. This _really_ needs to be fixed before VS2015 goes to RTM if `decltype(auto)` is intended to be anything other than useless...

Comment: Unfortunately MS Connect tells me that I am not authorized to submit bug reports. However within Visual Studio I have already done the next best thing - submitted feedback using their 'frowny face' including the screenshot of the test code with description. Unfortunately I dont think this method is trackable? Hopefully someone passes it along to the right department

Comment: Wsa this in VS2015 preview or VS2015 CTP5?  I can submit the bug report for you if you can send me a screen shot.  Then I'll include a trackable link in the answer.

Comment: Please don't put answers in comments, guys. This post is a perfect example of the model-breaking that ensues. We have facts in comments (which can disappear at any time) and a half-answer that doesn't provide any evidence, instead cross-referencing the comments (which can disappear at any time). If you want to discuss a question with your peers before answering it, try a chatroom!!

Comment: Bug is in latest CTP... Which I think is 5. I'll check on Monday and amend the SO question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [based on the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597) we can conclude:

- This is a bug in VS2015 preview
- There are workarounds
- The [bug has been reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1124457/decltype-auto-deducing-wrong-type-in-some-cases)

The bug is that:

- The compiler should have deduced the return type to be string
- It actually deduced it to be string &&
- Thus it destroyed the value prematurely

The workarounds are:

- Don't use decltype(auto) for the function's return type
- Wrap the function in a lambda expression before passing it in

Comment: Can we get those comments integrated into this answer? Comments are temporary.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1124457/decltype-auto-deducing-wrong-type-in-some-cases